# Netezza automatically rounding down decimal values

Tags: sql, casting, netezza

In Netezza, this expression automatically rounds down the result, how can I avoid that? I need to keep the original calculated value of 1.5, not 1

```
select cast ( (4 -1) / 2 AS NUMERIC (15,6)) as result --> gives 1.0000..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change one of arguments to `NUMERIC` to avoid integer division

```
SELECT (4 -1) / 2.0  AS result
```

or:

```
SELECT (4-1) / CAST(2 AS NUMERIC(15,6)) AS result
```

Division:

```
1 / 10   -> 0
1.0 / 10 -> 0.1
1 / 10.0 -> 0.1
1.0/10.0 -> 0.1
```